# session storage has not working as excepted using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage, session-storage

Currently working on session storage where if user select a radio button from the first page and in the next page i have to show one div and similarity for the second radio button Here there are two scenarios

1. In the first scenarios if user select ug from radio button and user click next button in the second page I have to show div_show (Div)
2. If the user select pg from the first radio group then al ain from the second radio group and finally DIP EDU from the select drop down. I have to show div in the second page (div_show1)

With my current code first scenarios working fine but the second scenarios partially working means i am getting the div but it was not hidding the first div do i want to remove session storage

Here i am using json with array

```
function storedata() {
    var storeDate = {};
    storeDate['storedValue1'] = $('input[id=pg]:checked').val();
    storeDate['storedValue2'] = $('input[id=alain]:checked').val();
    storeDate['storedValue3'] = $('#slt_mjrpg option:selected').val("Dip - Prof. PG Dip in Teaching");
    sessionStorage.setItem('storeDate', JSON.stringify(storeDate));
    console.log(storeDate);
 }

 function storedata1() {
    var storeDate1 = {};
    storeDate1['storedValuej'] = $('#slt_mjr option:selected').val()
    sessionStorage.setItem('storeDate1', JSON.stringify(storeDate1));
    console.log(storeDate1);
 }
```

In the second page

```
var otherObj === JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('storeDate'));
 if (otherObj.storedValue1 && otherObj.storedValue2 && otherObj.storedValue3) {
    console.log(otherObj);
    $(".div_show").show();
}

var otherObj1 === JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('storeDate1'));
if (otherObj1.storedValuej) {
    console.log(otherObj1);
    $(".div_show1").show();
}
```

Here is the html page first group

```
<div class="edu">
    <input type="radio" id="ug" name="edu" class="ug" value="ug" checked="checked">
    <label class="radio-label">Undergraduate</label>
    <input type="radio" id="pg" name="edu" value="pg" class="pg">
    <label class="radio-label">Postgraduate</label>
    <input type="radio" id="cu" name="edu" value="cu" class="cu">
    <label class="radio-label">Continuing Education</label>
</div>
```

Here is the second radio group in the first html page

```
<div class="rad_cam">
    <input type="radio" id="abudhabi" name="cam" value="abudhabi" checked>
    <label class="radio-label">Abu Dhabi</label>
    <input type="radio" id="alain" name="cam" value="alain">
    <label class="radio-label">Al Ain</label>
</div>
```

Here is the third element in the first html page

```
<select class="mslt_Field slt_mjrpg ipt_required" id="slt_mjrpg" name="slt_mjrpg">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="Dip - Prof. PG Dip in Teaching ">DIP EDU</option>
    <option value="Master of Science in Finance ">MASF</option>
    <option value="MBA">MBA 2013</option>
    <option value="MHRM">MHRM </option>
    <option value="MHRM">MHRM 2005</option>
    <option value="PhD-Doctor of Business Admin">PHDBA</option>
</select>
```

This my second HTML page

```
<div class="div_show">First</div>
<div class="div_show1">Second</div>
```

Comment: You didnt complete this scenario. Didint get the answer on yesterday?

Comment: no vel actually what is happening is for the first radio button was woking perfectly fine but for the second scenario this was not working

Comment: actually the problem is with the second session object it was not (otherObj1 ) if i removed this the first one is working fine :(

Comment: @vel kindly please help me on this

Comment: Im checking @Mahadevan... can you make fiddle? It is posssible?

Comment: @vel for the first page i can do how to connect for second page in fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95120/discussion-between-vel-and-mahadevan).